# Calculate the number of unique strings with the date, with a possible error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

In the select, I get rows from the table with time in the format TIMESTAMP. I want to count unique rows, **BUT with a possible error of 1 second**. In the example below, for example, 3 unique records (1 and 2 have an error of 1 second, and therefore counted as one).

I was thinking to make a function like **ABS(time_1 - time_2) > 1** to search for unique values.

1. Is it possible to implement this somehow on the SQL side, or would it be better to implement it on the server-side, which would be pulling this data?
2. Is it possible to do it without functions?
3. How much of a burden will this put on the database?

Any tips for solving the problem are welcome!

ps: I have an old version of SQL 5.7

Example output:

```
+------------+
|  time      |
+------------+
| 1583060400 |
+------------+
| 1583060401 |
+------------+
| 1583060460 |
+------------+
| 1583074860 |
+------------+
```

Comment: What if 3 rows "have an error of 1 second" (1583060400, 1583060401, 1583060402) - does they must be treated as one group? or two?

Comment: @Akina as one group

Comment: In which case, this is a gaps-and-islands problem

Comment: And 100-rows group with a gap of 1 second (and 99 second totally from the former till the latter) is one group too?

Comment: Use user-defined variable. It seems to be simple and effective (relatively to another methods) solution.

Comment: @Akina No. It's not possible. However, if it does happen (1583060400, 1583060401, 1583060402, 1583060403). Then count by the first entry. In this case there are 2 unique values (1583060400, 1583060402) and the values (1583060401, 1583060403) are skipped in the brackets.

Comment: *No. It's not possible.* None prevents it in the table structure - so it is possible. *However, if it does happen (1583060400, 1583060401, 1583060402, 1583060403). Then count by the first entry. In this case there are 2 unique values (1583060400, 1583060402) and the values (1583060401, 1583060403) are skipped in the brackets.* The logic "3 rows =1 group, but 4 rows = 2 groups" looks self-contradictory.

Comment: @Akina I hadn't thought about the option of multiple values with a difference of 1 second. I simply have not met them. I'm sorry if I didn't express myself accurately in my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "if a row TIMESTAMP differs from previous row TIMESTAMP by not more than 1 second then ignore this row presence" you may use

```sql
SELECT MAX(counter) groups_amount
FROM ( SELECT CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @previous, `time`) > 1
                   THEN @counter := @counter + 1
                   END counter,
              @previous := `time`
       FROM test
       CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @previous := '1970-01-01 00:00:01', 
                           @counter := 0 ) init_vars
       ORDER BY `time` ASC ) subquery;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2aba3b8f473e65f4f40e449c8d97a79d

Comment: Sorry, another stupid question. An example of how I get the lines: select unix_timestamp(date) from sometable where request = 11. How do I correctly substitute the query in your answer? :(

Comment: @Gravy ??? The task: *I want to count unique rows, BUT with a possible error of 1 second.* It does not need in timestamp-to-unixtime converting (or backward) or similar, and does not depend of this convertion. If your structure/data differs from one created in the fiddle then edit your question and provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, not as a table.  If you have some unrelated problem then you must create another question.

Comment: You are right. Thank you for your hard work and your time. I will not create an additional question and try to do it myself.